# Can someone explain how to select Multiple Values from an Access 2016 Combo box Control

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I have a combo box control on a form that allows me to choose one option only from a list of options.

I would like to be able to choose multiple options from this list(similar to how a drop down menu works on an access table field)

I know it is possible from a list box but this takes up a lot of room on my form because the list box must stay open.

It says in this article https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-list-that-stores-multiple-values-c8d15127-3641-45fc-aa2d-a3943d355e89 that its possible but I cannot get it to work. The article describes how it works under this heading "Understand the technology behind check-box drop-down lists and check box lists".

Answer (score 0):

I use 2007, not 2016.  Is multiselect combox something new? I haven't played with them yet.

Use right-click to change it to a List Box.    Microsoft Access > Design Form > List Box.  Property Sheet > Other tab > Multi Select = Extended.  List0.ListCount = quantity of rows in listbox (read only)

List0.ItemData(0) = value of bound column in first row (read only). 
List0.Column(0, 1) = value of first column in second row (read only). 
List0.Column(1, List0 - 1)  = value of second column in selected row (read only). 
List0.RowSource = "Hello; World" (write only).